# URL rewrites on web2py not working with routes.py

Tags: web2py

I'm trying to clean up the URL of an xmlrpc service I wrote on web2py so that the XMLRPC server URL is `http://myserver/rpc` rather than `http://myserver/MTN_SIM_Guard/db4listener/call/xmlrpc/`

I created routes.py and placed it in my web2py directory:

```
routes_in = (
  ('/rpc/$anything', '/MTN_SIM_Guard/db4listener/call/xmlrpc/$anything'),
)

routes_out = [(x, y) for (y, x) in routes_in]
```

Accept, this doesn't work:

```
invalid request
```

Help?

Comment: Have you either reloaded routes (via the admin interface) or restarted the web server since updating the routes.py file?

Comment: Yep. Managed to get it to work by setting a default app, but this is not ideal.